# Can the random seed of HashCode in C# be considered cryptographically random?

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, hashcode

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode?view=net-5.0)  of `HashCode` mentions that a 'random seed' is used that is 'only deterministic within the scope of an operating system process'.

My questions are:

- How is this random seed implemented? Can this random seed be considered cryptographically random?

Comment: _"for this type of application"_ - what type of application?

Comment: What makes you think it would be cryptographically random? What benefit would that offer when nobody is using it for cryptography?

Comment: That hash is used to sort objects into buckets for quicker comparison. It is very specifically designed to be not random and to represent the contents of the object.

Comment: Unfortunately, "this type of application" as in "create hashes to access control certain resources" doesn't have enough details for anyone here to judge whether this is suitable or not. You would have to describe the process in much more detail for us to be able to judge this.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I edited my question to remove the part that cannot be judged.

Comment: Even if the seed was cryptographically random the hash function is likely not cryptographically secure, nor is it designed to be. These random seeds are likely used for the limited purpose of thwarting hash flooding DoS attacks. See [SipHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a look. The source for `HashCode` [is here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashCode.cs,5f9e3dc86db22de1).  We can see the line:

```
private static readonly uint s_seed = GenerateGlobalSeed();
```

So let's take a look at [`GenerateGlobalSeed`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashCode.cs,b80ccd7c36f40322):

```
private static unsafe uint GenerateGlobalSeed()
{
    uint result;
    Interop.GetRandomBytes((byte*)&result, sizeof(uint));
    return result;
}
```

OK, and [`Interop.GetRandomBytes`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Interop.GetRandomBytes.cs,466e9a485f6750aa):

```
Sys.GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes(buffer, length);
```

Pretty big give-away there: **NonCryptographicallySecure**RandomBytes. This is not a cryptographic source.

If we look further at [the implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7414af2a5f6d8d99efc27d3f5ef7a394e0b23c42/src/native/libs/System.Native/pal_random.c#L26), we can see that it uses `arc4random_buf` or `lrand48`, which very definitely aren't cryptographic.

Even if the seed was cryptographic, note that the it's constant for an entire process. It wouldn't be particularly hard to figure out what it is, depending on what sort of attack you're guarding against.